# Missing equality between shared_ptr and weak_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

While I do understand why there is no `operator==` for `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`, I wonder why there is none for `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`. Especially since you can create a `weak_ptr` via a reference on `shared_ptr`.
I would assume that for 99% of the time you want `lhs.get() == rhs.get()`. I would now go forward and introduce that into my code unless someone can name me a good reason, why one should not do such a thing.

Comment: But `weak_ptr` doesn't have a `get` method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`weak_ptr` doesn' have a `get()` method because you need to explicitly lock the `weak_ptr` before you can access the underlying pointer. Making this explicit is a deliberate design decision. If the conversion were implicit it would be very easy to write code that would be unsafe if the last `shared_ptr` to the object were to be destroyed while the underlying pointer obtained from the `weak_ptr` was still being examined.

[This boost page](http://www.boost.org/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm) has a good description of the pitfalls and why `weak_ptr` has such a limited interface.

If you need to do a quick comparison, then you can do `shared == weak.lock()`. If the comparison is true then you know that `weak` must still be valid as you hold a separate `shared_ptr` to the same object. There is no such guarantee if the comparison returns false.

Comment: Calling `lock` for a larger part of code does really make more sense. Good design decision.

Comment: Calling `lock` is unnecessarily expensive and does not offer a stable comparison.  See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Because it has a cost.

A `weak_ptr` is like an observer, not a real pointer. To do any work with it you first need to obtain a `shared_ptr` from it using its `lock()` method.

This has the effect of acquiring ownership, but it as costly as copying a regular `shared_ptr` (count increment, etc...) so it is nothing trivial.

As such, by not providing `==`, you are forced to step back and actually check whether you really need this or not.

Comment: I’m not sure that comparing equality needs to care about validity, and as such could be implemented cheaply: either the `weak_ptr` refers to the same entity, in which case it must be valid (or 0), or it refers to another entity, in which case we don’t care whether it’s valid.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: maybe, maybe not. But because obtaining the pointer would be unsafe in general (since you would have the pointer but would not be able to access the pointee), you cannot get the pointer from `weak_ptr` and are forced to go through a `shared_ptr`. So...

Comment: No, obtaining the pointer is safe, as long as it’s done *internally*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Ah, I see what you mean. Yes internally it would be possible the way it is implemented now. However it would restrict the way `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` can be implemented for a quite limited use-case.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers have pointed out, simply comparing the underlying pointers would be perilous.  For one, consider the following scenario: a weak reference A exists to an object, which is subsequently deleted, and therefore the weak reference expires.  Then, another object is allocated in the memory freed up by said deletion, which has the same address.  Now the underlying pointers are the same, even though the weak pointer originally referred to a different object!

As the other answers have suggested, one way is to compare `shared == weak.lock()`.  Since `lock()` will return `nullptr` (and not some bogus pointer) if the weak pointer expired, his works for identifying if they are equal (as long as `shared != nullptr`).  However, there are two problems with this:

- It stops working when the weak pointer expires, in which case the comparison changes; after the expiration, it will only return true if `shared == nullptr`.  This can be dangerous in cases where the comparison must remain stable, such as when using it as a key in an `unordered_map` or `unordered_set`.
- `lock()` is a relatively expensive operation.

Fortunately, there is a better way to do this.  Both `weak_ptr` and `shared_ptr` also store a pointer to what is known as the *control block*, which is what stores the reference counts and outlives the original object for as long as references remain to it.  To check whether they refer to the same object, all we need to do is compare the control block pointers.  This can be done with the `owner_before` method:

```
template<class T>
bool owner_equals(std::shared_ptr<T> &lhs, std::weak_ptr<T> &rhs) {
    return !lhs.owner_before(rhs) && !rhs.owner_before(lhs);
}
```

This approach will even work for comparing two `std::weak_ptr`s with each other, if you wish to know whether they (once) referred to the same object, since the control block will last (at least) as long as all of the weak references.

Do keep in mind that this may not produce the expected result if you are using the aliasing feature of `std::shared_ptr`, which is a feature that lets you create two `std::shared_ptr` instances with the same control block that nonetheless store different pointers.